# How to read excel file present in URI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use EPPLUS to read excel file. Excel file is present in URL.

How to do that

Below code throwing errors

```
byte[] bin = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(URL);
```

I am trying to read excel file present in sharepoint site. I have access to the file.

I am able to read sharepoint site excel data using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

But I want to do read data using EPPLUS as I heard EPPLUS has improved performance over Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

I tried to download excel file using `HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)` but getting 403 forbidden error where as I am able access using Interop.Excel

Comment: It would be helpful to know the error. The question as it is now is impossible to answer since the row code you posted in correct on it's own.

Comment: I am getting 403 forbidden error with below code                 var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;

Comment: A 403 error is pretty clear. You do not have access.

Comment: I am able to access sharepoint excel document by browsing

Comment: Browsing and website access are not the same thing.

Comment: I have website access. I am able to view SharePoint excel file data in any browser.